# How can I select a specific PowerPoint slide and duplicate it?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking for a simple VBA code which would do the following:

-> Open a specific PowerPoint presentation (template)

-> Select a specific slide then duplicate it

For now I have this

```
Sub pres()

    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test.pptx"
    PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Duplicate

End Sub
```

Which opens the presentation but does nothing and returns me an error 429.

Would anyone have any idea of how to do that very simple task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Presentations.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentations.open) returns a `Presentation` object that you should capture, like this:

```
Sub pres()
    Dim PowerPointApp as Object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    Dim myPres as Object
    Set myPres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test.pptx")

    PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    myPres.Slides(8).Duplicate
End Sub
```